# changing textview when edittext changes in a dynamically created tablelayout with anywhere from 1 to 50 rows?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am not a programmer I just like to make apps that help me for my work so I dont know alot about programming properly.  That being said this is what I am up against.  I enter a number for 1 to 100 and then my app will create a scrollable tablelayout with that many rows.  Each row has a textview, an edittext and another textview here my code:

```
TableLayout tL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    // creates all the fields
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfInjWells; i++) {
        TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
        // creates the textView
        TextView tV1 = new TextView(this);
        tV1.setText("      " + i + ":    ");

        // add edit text
        EditText eT = new EditText(this);
        eT.setText("Meter Reading");
        eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        TextView tV2 = new TextView(this);
        tV2.setText("");

        // add the TextView and the editText to the new TableRow
        tR.addView(tV1);
        tR.addView(eT);
        tR.addView(tV2);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tL.addView(tR,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
    } // end for statement
```

so when I input a number in the edittext (eT) of row one I want it to then calculate the difference between it and a number I have stored in my database (I already know how to get the specific number I need from the database) and then change the textview tV2 in row one so it displays the difference without clicking a button.  The problem that I am coming across is how do I associate edittext (eT) in row one with textview (tV2) because all the edittext and textviews have the same name eT or tV2

thanks for you help and I am sorry that I dont know much about coding.

edit: I thought about adding

```
eT.setId(i);
tV2.setId(i);
```

but I dont know how to use that in my calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into listview I couldnt get them to work with the edittext so I went back to my tablelayout and this is the final working version.

Here I create the fields and a textwatcher added to the edittext to watch for changes:

```
    TableLayout tL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    // creates all the fields
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfInjWells; i++) {
        TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
        // creates the textView
        TextView tV1 = new TextView(this);
        tV1.setText("       " + i + ":    ");

        // add edit text
        eT = new EditText(this);
        eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        eT.setWidth(100);
        eT.setId(1000 + i);
        eT.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(eT));

        tV2 = new TextView(this);
        tV2.setText("");
        tV2.setId(2000 + i);

        // add the TextView and the editText to the new TableRow
        tR.addView(tV1);
        tR.addView(eT);
        tR.addView(tV2);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tL.addView(tR,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
    } // end for statement
```

next I created this class for my customtextwachter:

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText eT) {
        mEditText = eT;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // gets the change amount for each meter reading from the previous reading
            // this method does the work
        getMeterChange();

    }
} // end class CustomTextWatcher
```

the getMeterChange() method does the work:

```
public void getMeterChange() {
    int preMeterReading = 0;
    int mReading = 0;

    try {
        cRWLogData.moveToPosition(recordLookUp - 1);
        preMeterReading = cRWLogData.getInt( 14 + rowChanged);
        // finds the edittext that has focus
        View currView = tL.findFocus();
        int currentid = tL.findFocus().getId();
        // gets the string from the edittext and changes it to a int
        EditText currentComponent = (EditText) currView;
        String eTValue = currentComponent.getText().toString();
        mReading = Integer.parseInt(eTValue);
        // calculates difference for what is entered and what is in database
        mChange = mReading - preMeterReading;
        // makes the textview in the same tablerow as the edittext active
        TextView tV2 = (TextView) findViewById(currentid + 1000);
        // sets the text of the textview
        tV2.setText("     " + mChange +"");
    } // end try
    catch (Exception e) {}

} // end getMeterChange
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that I am coming across is how do I associate edittext
>   (eT) in row one with textview (tV2) because all the edittext and
>   textviews have the same name eT or tV2

One simple option is to set ids for this two `Views` that have a relation between them and when a particular `EditText` is modified you would find out which `TextView` is near the `EditText` an update it. For example to set the ids:

```
// add edit text
EditText eT = new EditText(this);
et.setId(1000 + i);
eT.setText("Meter Reading");
eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

TextView tV2 = new TextView(this);
tV2.setId(2000 + i); // as you see the difference between the this id and the EditText is 1000
tV2.setText("");
```

So if you have a reference to the `EditText` for which you want to calculate the value you could simple do a `findViewById` by the id of the `EditText` to which you add `1000`. Now, I don't know how exactly you calculate the value based on the `EditText`, if you use a `TextWatcher` you could make your own class(that implements the `TextWatcher` interface) which also takes an `int` representing the id of the `EditText` for which you set the watcher and find the desired `TextView` from that.

Also, note that at 3 `Views` per row(+ 1 the `TableRow`) you could get in trouble with the app's memory if you create 50 rows or more(as this will result in about 200 `Views` in your layout). Might worth looking at the `ListView`.

Comment: I have looked into the listviews but because of my lack of knowledge of coding I am getting lost with them or I cant get them to compile without errors.  I have been trying to find tutorials to help me with it but I have not came up with any close enough to what I am doing that I can manipulate to my needs.  thanks for your help I will try this and see if I can make it work

Comment: @deerkiller11 Did you manage to do something? Also my advice with a `ListView` might not be such a good idea because an `EditText` in a `ListView` row doesn't work to well. Another approach could be to keep the current table layout and build some kind of pagination to only show a part of the table.

Comment: not yet I am looking into the listview option but I have not been able to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for those who found this when searching I'll update a better option...

```
TableLayout tL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
// creates all the fields
for(int i = 1; i <= numOfInjWells; i++) {
    TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
    // creates the textView
    TextView tV1 = new TextView(this);
    tV1.setText("       " + i + ":    ");

    // add edit text
    eT = new EditText(this);
    eT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    eT.setWidth(100);


    tV2 = new TextView(this);
    tV2.setText("");
    eT.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(tV2));

    // add the TextView and the editText to the new TableRow
    tR.addView(tV1);
    tR.addView(eT);
    tR.addView(tV2);

    // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tL.addView(tR,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
} // end for statement
```

Then the watcher:

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private TextView mTextView;

    public CustomTextWatcher(TextView tV2) {
        mTextView = tV2;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // gets the change amount for each meter reading from the previous reading
            // this method does the work

        cRWLogData.moveToPosition(recordLookUp - 1);
        preMeterReading = cRWLogData.getInt( 14 + rowChanged);
        // edit text has just passed the value in Editable s
        mReading = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        // calculates difference for what is entered and what is in database
        mChange = mReading - preMeterReading;
        // sets the text of the textview
        mTextView.setText("     " + mChange +"");

    }
} // end class CustomTextWatcher
```

There's a reason the values are passed into the watcher. Use the framework to do the hard yards for you.

NOTE: I haven't actually compiled this, and you would likely need to put the try/catch back in, I simply removed it for clarity.